# AutoMapper - object to object different namespaces

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a scenario where we have two services that reference an object definition dll which is called `SLInterface.dll`.  This is just a compilation of our object model.  This object is huge so I'll tone it down and give a snippet of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SLInterface
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = Utilities.strNamespace)]
public class EntityShipment
{

    public EntityShipment()
    {
        lstEntityResponseStatus = new List<EntityResponseStatus>();
    }
    [DataMember]
    public EntityAddress objShipTo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public EntityToolKit ToolKit { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<EntityResponseStatus> lstEntityResponseStatus
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

 }

}

namespace SLInterface
{
public class EntityAddress
{
    [DataMember]
    public String strCustomerID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strCompanyName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strContactName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strAddressLine1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strAddressLine2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strAddressLine3
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strCity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strState
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strPostalCode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strCountryCode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strCountryName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strPhoneNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strFaxNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public Boolean blnRBDICheck
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public Boolean blnIsRBDI
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strPlantID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strAccountNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public String strEmailAddress
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public Boolean blnBlindShip
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
}
```

And Then there is another definition for toolkit and for `EntityResponseStatus` which I can post if it is needed.

We have a scenario where from `ServiceA`, we need to pass this object to `ServiceB`.  We can't just pass this object that is filled during `ServiceA` as it is a different namespace.  So we're trying to use `AutoMapper` so we don't have to map each property and it values individually.

Here is our AutoMapperCode:

```
public class ES
{

    public ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityResponseStatus CallES(string strPrinterPath, string strShipmentNumber, string strCompanyCode)
    {

        Mapper.CreateMap<ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityShipment, ServiceB.SLInterface.EntityShipment>();

        ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityResponseStatus objERS = new ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityResponseStatus();
        objERS.StatusType = ServiceA.SLInterface.ResponseStatusType.SUCCESS;

        ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityShipment objES = new ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityShipment();

        objES = FillES(objES, strShipmentNumber, strCompanyCode);

        Sage300 obj300 = new Sage300();
        objES = obj300.Pull(objES);

         ServiceB.SLInterface.EntityShipment objESES = new ServiceB.SLInterface.EntityShipment();
        try
        {

            objESES = Mapper.Map<ServiceB.SLInterface.EntityShipment>(objES);  //This is the line that we blow up on.  The error message is "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."
        }
        catch(AutoMapperConfigurationException amce)
        {
            ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityResponseStatus objERS1 = new ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityResponseStatus();
            objERS1.Message = amce.Message;
        }
        catch (AutoMapperMappingException amme)
        {
            ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityResponseStatus objERS1 = new ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityResponseStatus();
            objERS1.Message = amme.Message;
        }

        objESES = ServiceB.CallESShip(objESES,strPrinterPath);

        return objERS;
    }
```

In the `try catch` is where we get the error message
`objESES = Mapper.Map<ServiceB.SLInterface.EntityShipment>(objES);`  //This is the line that we blow up on.  The error message is `"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."`

Both object models are exactly the same.  Do we have to do a mapping for each object in the main object.  Right now, we are thinking with the code that we have that it would be mapping everything from the root down exactly the same and then transferring over the data.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to map each property from source to destination objects. If you do not want to map then you need to `ignore` that property by using  `.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt=> opt.Ignore())` while creating the `Map`

Comment: Hi Venky, thanks for the response.  I'm not sure I follow the solution.  I have one "Master Object" EntityShipment that has many properties which are of type a different object.  EntityShipment and all of the objects under it are filled in in ServiceA, I want to pass that to EntityShipment object to ServiceB.  With the AutoMapper, how would I map different then doing the mapping of both entityShipment objects?  Would I use your .ForMember but remove the opt.Ignore() and it will go through all properties and map them automatically?

Comment: if you do not add `.ForMember` then it looks for properties with the same `name` while mapping. If you have different property names in both the objects then you need to `map` each one using `.ForMember`. Otherwise `AutoMapper` will not understand how to map. If you have a pattern in the naming of properties such as they have a common `prefix` or `suffix` then you can tell `AutoMapper` to use that prefix or suffix while mapping.   Automapper is dumb, it just maps the properties based on how we define.

Comment: I don't see code where you are creating a map between both objects. `Mapper.CreateMap<ServiceB.SLInterface.EntityShipment, ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityShipment>();`  First you need to `createmap` then you can use `mapper.map` to  map the objects.

Comment: The First Snippet of code is the object model, the second snippet of code is how it is implemented.  In the second snippet of code 3rd line we are doing this:
        Mapper.CreateMap<ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityShipment, ServiceB.SLInterface.EntityShipment>();
Then middle of the way through the second snippet we are doing this:
            objESES = Mapper.Map<ServiceB.SLInterface.EntityShipment>(objES);  This is the line that we blow up on.  The error message is "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."
Both EntityShipments are exactly the same property names and structure.

Comment: Ok. The error shows you which properties are not mapped.  Can you share the inner exception that you are getting. Also it is good practice to put all the Mapper Configurations in a static global file to be accessible across the application and easy to maintain.

Comment: Also you need to configure Automapper before using it. have a look at this link on how to configure https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: The inner exception is null, however, here is the full message:
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
EntityToolKit -> EntityToolKit
SLInterface.EntityToolKit -> ESInterface.ExpressShipper.EntityToolKit

Destination path:
EntityShipment.ToolKit.ToolKit

Source value:
SLInterface.EntityToolKit

Comment: It is trying to map `EntityToolKit` to `ToolKit`. Hence it is unable to map as the names are different. You need to use `Mapper.CreateMap<ServiceB.SLInterface.EntityShipment, ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityShipment>().ForMember(dest => dest.EntityToolkit, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ToolKit)).ReverseMap();`    Try this.

Comment: Thanks Venky, but that does not work as there is no     dest.EntityToolkit in the dest object there is dest.Toolkit.  "EntityToolkit" is the properties type and the name of the property is Toolkit.  When I saw that in the exception message as well, it makes no sense to me.  If I declare the object and then use intellisense both toolkit properties and underlying properties are exactly the same name.

Comment: i think you need to create an explicit map for EntityToolkit as well.  `Mapper.CreateMap<ServiceB.SLInterface.EntityShipment.EntityToolkit ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityShipment.EntityToolkit>().ReverseMap()`  add this line after the first `CreateMap` statement.

Comment: I can't do that either because EntityToolkit object is defined at ServiceA.SLInterface.EntityToolkit.  EntityShipment just has a property called Toolkit that is of type EntityToolKit.

Comment: you need to make sure you have same number of properties in both the objects while you are mapping. Otherwise you need to  `Ignore` the extra properties which are not present in both objects. If we configure it properly then Automapper will work like a charm. I don't think i can be of more helpful.

Comment: Thanks Venky, I can understand as we're at a loss as well.  The two entityShipment objects are literally exactly the same thing they are both referencing exactly the same dll which contains the object model.  There might be a bug with AutoMapper that we're currently looking into.  I appreciate the tips.